# How can I minimize this function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function, that is on the form

$$ f(t,p) = c_1 t^{-\frac{4}{3}} + c_2 p^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-c_3 p} - c_4 p e^{c_5 p} t^{-2} + c_6 t^{-3}  $$
where t and p are variables and $c_n$ are constants.

Is it possible to Minimize this function in terms of the constants? Mathematica cannot solve take $\partial_p f = 0$. But I cannot really use the Minimize command on constants?

If I let all constants be one,  just to see how the function behave in a crude manner, I get

```
Plot3D[(1 t^(-3) + t^(-4/3)   +  Sqrt[ p] E^(-p))/t + ( p E^(-1 p))/(t^2), {t, -10^2, 10^2}, {p, -10^2, 10^2}]
```

[![Plot where constants are unity][1]][1]

I can try to use the FindMinimum command:

```
FindMinimum[(1 t^(-3) + t^(-4/3)   +  Sqrt[ p] E^(-t))/p + ( p E^(-1 p))/(t^2), {t, p}]
```

I get the result:

```
{4.10656*10^-19, {t -> 7.58469*10^7, p -> 1.54318*10^7}}
```

Which I guess looks reasonable judging on the plot. But Ideally, I would like to find the minimum in terms of the constants. Is that possible?

Comment: Where did $x,y$ come from in your result? You mention $t,p$ and the $c_i$ in your $f(t,p)$ but no $x,y$. When you say _Minimize this function in terms of the constants_ do you want to allow the constants to vary *and* t and p to vary? or do you want to fix t,p and allow only the constants to vary? or do you want to find the constants c that minimize the function over a range of t,p coordinates? (in which case please provide the range). Also what are the constraints on the constants as without constraints I could make them all $-\infty$ and that would be the minimum.

Comment: Is it not possible to find an algebraic expression? If I want to minimize $x^2 + b$, I know the minimum lives at $b$.

Comment: Recommend first just studying the function for chosen values of parameters in some range 0<p<pt and 0<t<te since have radicals of these variables and then come up with a method to compute the minimum in terms of t and p.  Here's example $$-\frac{e^{p/65} p}{28 t^2}+\frac{e^{-\frac{p}{16}}}{17 \sqrt{p}}+\frac{1}{6 t^{4/3}}+\frac{7}{92 t^3} $$ . How to find minimum of that in 0<t<5 and 0<p<5 maybe?

Comment: @JohnGreger Can you please respond to my other points in the comment, as it is not clear from the question how you want to minimize the expression, and what constraints you want to impose. Without constraints, the minimum is easy - it's just $-\infty$.

Comment: Hi @flinty, 

Thanks for pointing out that the function diverges, that was not obvious to me. It is not clear to me the precise constraints on this function.I would like to ignore that and get a purely algebraic expression.